# The type or namespace name 'AsyncOperationHandle<>' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, addressables

Just got started trying to work with Addressables in unity, but I've been provided with the "namespace not found" exception, even though I have all the 'using' statements and the correct type from the unity documentation for Unity Addressables 1.19.19.

The code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AddressableAssets;
using UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations;

using ONSDK.Utility; // Personal utility class.

namespace ONSDK.PlayerModel
{
    public class PlayerModelManager : Singleton<PlayerModelManager> // Singleton<> is provided by 'ONSDK.Utility'.
    {
        private AsyncOperationHandle<GameObject> handle; // The "missing" type.
        private void Start()
        {
            // Gonna load a player model here.
        }
    }
}
```

*Side note:*
The script is located in a folder with an Assembly Definition that is referencing the Unity.Addressables assembly definition, all using statements are fine, but its just the AsyncOperationHandle type that just isn't found, even though it's in the AsyncOperations class provided by the using statement...

Answer (score 1):

To anyone that finds them selves in this situation of, separating your code into a separate assembly definition; be sure to reference these assembly definitions so you can use addressable in your code:

- Unity.Addresssables
- Unity.ResourceManager